# Improve questions that are off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, suggested-edits

I was looking at the suggested edits, and came across [this edit suggestion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/104591), about [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119492/i-uninstalled-microsoft-edge-browser-i-cant-restore-it-win-10) question.

The question is off-topic, since it's about a browser, and more likely to be on-topic on superuser, if fits their requirements.

So should I approve edits or suggest of my own, if the question is likely to be deleted from WebApps? I think that it can be helpful to edit in such cases, so it will be more readable when a mod or more high rep user looks at it. But I couldn't find any guideline about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, I would say not to bother. The first rule of migrations is "don't migrate crap", and the original form of that question certainly applies.

However, after cleaning up this would actually be a decent question, admittedly for Super User. So, for *this case*, I would say the edit should be approved. (Be sure to also vote to migrate.)

Comment: Thanks! as a side question - I remember from the past the I should vote to migrate, only if it fits and not a duplicate on the destination site, correct?

Comment: It's not incumbent on you to search for duplicates at the target. And, yes, you should only vote to migrate if the question is obviously a good fit on the target site and _completely_ off-topic here.